# or in if-statement doesn't work

Tags: c#, if-statement

I tried the following , I want to get a message if the entered number isn't 1, 2 or 3 :

```
Console.WriteLine("which number?");
int number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
if (number != 1 || number != 2 || number != 3)
{
    Console.WriteLine("wrong number!");
}
```

but also if my input is 1,2 or 3 I get the message , but why ? whats wrong ? :/ there is no error by visual studio.

Comment: use `&&`  - "And" operator

Answer (score 1):

You should use `AND` operator in that if statement

```
if (number != 1 && number != 2 && number != 3)
{
    Console.WriteLine("wrong number!");
}
```

or in this case you can use

```
if (number <= 0 || number >= 4)
{
    Console.WriteLine("wrong number!");
}
```

Comment: Your second answer will not work, if he enters -4 then it will result in a valid number, however your first case is correct

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using && operator which will check for at least number does not belong to one of those

```
if (number != 1 && number != 2 && number != 3)
{
    Console.WriteLine("wrong number!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## You're confusing English with C#.

**TL;DR**: *Use the `&&` operator to check for all three, instead of just checking for any of the three.*

---

You're currently checking: if the number is either *not one*, or *not two*, or *not three*, then say "wrong number".

```
if (number != 1 || number != 2 || number != 3)
```

Take, for example, `number = 1`.  The code will first check whether `number != 1`, and will return false.  However, since you're using an OR statement, it will check the next one.  What ends up happening is this:

```
if (false || true || true)
```

Since you're using OR, C# checks to see if *ANY* of those are `true`.  So this further simplifies to the following:

```
if (true)
```

Since a number can not be `!=1`, `!=2`, and `!=3` at the same time, **this will always have at least two `true`s**.  Therefore, if you use the OR operator, the expression will *always return true*

What you want is the `&&` operator.

```
//if number is NOT 1 AND NOT 2 AND NOT 3
if (number != 1 && number != 2 && number != 3)
```

With the example above, this would simplify to this:

```
if (false && true && true)
```

Which goes further to:

```
if (false)
    //wrong number
```

Which will skip the inside, because 1 **is a right number**.  If 1, 2, and 3 are *wrong numbers*, just put an exclamation point before the entire block, as follows:

```
if (!(number != 1 && number != 2 && number != 3))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I take a look at your code

```
Console.WriteLine("which number?");
int number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
if (number != 1 || number != 2 || number != 3)
{
    Console.WriteLine("wrong number!");
}
```

lets say number is now equal to 1 `if (1 != 1 || 1 != 2 || 1 != 3)` this will give the following using Truth tables `if ( false || true || true )`
this will then result in `if (true)`

For more information about truth tables you can visit http://kias.dyndns.org/comath/21.html but in short using the stroke

true || true = true

true || false = true

false || true = true

false || false = false

But if you look at using the ampersand
true && true = true

true && false = false

false && false = false

This is the reason why you will always get to line `Console.WriteLine("wrong number!");` because if you enter 1,2,3 you will get atleast 2 'True' values, you have a number of options that you can follow

1) `if (number != 1 || number != 2 || number != 3)`
changes to `if (number != 1 && number != 2 && number != 3)`
2) make an array for valid values
`int[] valid = new int[] {1,2,3}`
Then test if the input is inside of the valid array using a for loop or the easy Linq method Contains(...)

```
Console.WriteLine("which number?");
int number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
if (!valid.Contains(number))
{
    Console.WriteLine("wrong number!");
}
```

Note I have added a Not operator infront of valid (!), this means if valid does not contain the value